# Python name error after importing file

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I'm playing with Python on my Mac, it's the default installation, version 2.7.2. For some reason, when I import a file in my current directory, it successfully imports, but when I try to call a function in the file, it gives me: `NameError: name 'gcd' is not defined`

This is what's inside the file (`lab1.py`):

```
def gcd(x, y):
    if x % y == 0:
        return y
    else:
        return gcd(y, x % y)

def f(x):
    return x*x
```

At the prompt, I just type `import lab1`. It imports successfully. Notably, if I'm not in the directory with lab1.py it errors out, so I know it's getting the right file. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to names in the module via the global name you imported.

If you import *just* `lab1`, then refer to names in that module as attributes on the module object:

```
lab1.gcd(10, 3)
```

or you need to import names *from* the module:

```
from lab1 import gcd
```

to create a reference in your current module to the same function. An alternative spelling would be:

```
import lab1.gcd as gcd
```

Comment: Oh duh. That makes sense. For some reason I don't remember this from my last encounter with python.